# Generating Jenkinsfile for (Spring) Cloud Pipeline

Tags: spring-cloud

I came across Spring Cloud Pipeline (which is now Cloud Pipeline). The docs are not very clear and I have gone through the new ones for [scripts](https://cloudpipelines.github.io/scripts/) and [jenkins](https://cloudpipelines.github.io/jenkins/) projects.

What I would like to do is generate the opinionated Jenkinsfile for my existing repo (Spring boot/gradle project) and deploy to my existing Jenkins. How can I do that?

Thanks